# How can I set the background color in react-navigation 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)@5.0.0 and I have added a background color to my root `<View />`.

It seems that another view created by react-navigation is having some background color set, because I can't see my background. (Just as an example, I Can see the dark background when I use react-router)

How can I set the background color of a page using react-navigation v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but I'll leave it to you just in case.

It is a matter of Expo from what I have managed to investigate. Expo does not have support for changing (as far as I have found information) the root view color for Android and iOS from Expo without Ejecting your project. Apparently to be able to modify that, it is required to use the command `eject` and alter said behavior in Android and iOS projects on ther respective languages and supported features. There is a workaround with Expo but personally it is not practical at all